# How to check null condition with multiple list select in c#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

In my select statement i would like to check null or empty.

```
        [HttpGet("service")]
        public IActionResult GetService()
        {
            var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile("project.conf");
            IKubernetes client = new Kubernetes(config);
            var volumeList = client.ListNamespacedService("default");
            var result = from item in volumeList.Items
                select new
                {
                    MetadataName = item.Metadata.Name,
                    Namespace = item.Metadata.NamespaceProperty,
                    Age = item.Metadata.CreationTimestamp,
                    Type = item.Spec.Type,
                    All = item.Status,
                    Ip = item.Status.LoadBalancer.Ingress.Select(x => x.Ip)
                };
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Json result is :

```
 {
        "metadataName": "cred-mgmt-redis-slave",
        "namespace": "default",
        "age": "2019-12-20T09:50:11Z",
        "type": "ClusterIP",
        "all": {
            "loadBalancer": {
                "ingress": null
            }
        }       
    },
    {
        "metadataName": "jenkins",
        "namespace": "default",
        "age": "2020-01-01T16:38:58Z",
        "type": "LoadBalancer",
        "all": {
            "loadBalancer": {
                "ingress": [
                    {
                        "hostname": null,
                        "ip": "185.22.98.93"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }       
    }
```

I know in my case ingress is null and in this case I got null reference exception. I need to check ingress if it is not null show ip.

Comment: Have you tried using the '?.' syntax? e.g. item.Status.LoadBalancer?.Ingress.Select(x => x.Ip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `?` operator:

```
var result = from item in volumeList.Items
    select new
    {
        MetadataName = item.Metadata?.Name,
        Namespace = item.Metadata?.NamespaceProperty,
        Age = item.Metadata?.CreationTimestamp,
        Type = item.Spec?.Type,
        All = item?.Status,
        Ip = item.Status?.LoadBalancer?.Ingress.Select(x => x.Ip)
    };
```

This operator `?` is available in C# 6 and later. In your example, it means:

```
Ip = (item.Status.LoadBalancer.Ingress == null ? null  : item.Status.LoadBalancer.Ingress)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use "?" operator

```
Ip = item.Status.LoadBalancer.Ingress?.Select(x => x.Ip)
```

Or

```
Ip = item.Status?.LoadBalancer?.Ingress?.Select(x => x.Ip)
```

In this case, there will be no exception and you will assign value to IP only if Ingress is not null

Comment: Only if Ingress is not null no ?